# It ended with an AFTERSHOCK

Tags: word, no-computers

I started with a single-letter English language word. At each step, I added a letter of my choice, then re-arranged the letters to make a new word. I ended up with:

> AFTERSHOCK

How did I get there? There may be more than one solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I took **a** look **at** my plans for the meal. This was going to be a work of **art**, a **star** turn at which everyone would **stare**. I began by weighing out my **caster** sugar and, after being distracted by making sure that every place setting had a **coaster**, added it bit by bit to my **charoset** to get the balance of sweetness just right. But when my guests discovered that I had unconventionally decided to serve it with **shortcake**, the **aftershock** began...

Comment: Lovely! And a different 9-letter than I chose (I think there are only two that work), so even better. And a cheery story to boot. Full marks.

Comment: Qat lists my word as well as rot13(ebpxfunsg, gnfxsbepr, naq genpxfubr), all of which I would be more inclined to write as two words each. One defect in my story is that I think rot13(punebfrg vf zrnag gb or fjrrgrarq jvgu ubarl engure guna fhtne), but let's call that poetic licence.

Comment: Much the trickiest part was finding a good candidate 9-letter word. And then a good candidate 8-letter word. I tried to rot13(trg evq bs njxjneq yrggref svefg) and it seemed to work out fairly well.

Comment: My path was (gnfxsbepr) which only has one possible descendant. (ebpxfunsg) seems to be a dead end. Well done, that was very fast.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the numerous solutions (many anagrams)

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE CHASER ARCHEST CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE CHASER CHASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE CHASTE ARCHEST CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE CHASTE CHASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE SACHET ARCHEST CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE SACHET CHASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE SEARCH ARCHEST CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CHASE SEARCH CHASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CRASH CHASER ARCHEST CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH CRASH CHASER CHASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO ACTOR SCROTA COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO ROAST CASTOR COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO ROAST COSTAR COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO ROAST SCROTA COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO SORTA CASTOR COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO SORTA COSTAR COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TARO SORTA SCROTA COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORE STORE CORSET COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORE STORE ESCORT COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORE STORE SECTOR COASTER CHAROSET SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES ARCHES ARCHEST THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES ARCHES CHASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES ARCHES ROACHES THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHASER ARCHEST THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHASER CHASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHASER ROACHES THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHASTE ARCHEST THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHASTE CHASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHEATS ARCHEST THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> A AH ASH CASH ACHES CHEATS CHASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS STORE SECTOR TORCHES THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS STORE THROES EARSHOT THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS STORE THROES HECTORS THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS STORE THROES TORCHES THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS TAROS ACTORS COASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS TAROS CASTOR COASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS TAROS COSTAR COASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS TAROS ORATES COASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS TAROS ORATES EARSHOT THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK

or

> O TO TOR TORS TAROS SCROTA COASTER THORACES SHORTCAKE AFTERSHOCK